# Is there any default php method to uses the deprecated end() function php8.1?

Tags: php, php8

end() function is deprecated in php8.1 and have tried to find the default PHP method but seems for an end() method replacement there is no same working method anywhere.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php Have also reviewed this page but was unable to get the exact solution as the end() method was provided.

If anyone has the solution with the default method in php8.1 as above concerned please share.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is only deprecated for usage with objects. It is still okay to use on arrays. How are you using it?

Comment: Hello @AydinHassan, I was checking with the use on the array, and there returned a deprecated method warning. I have used another way to implement this. Ignore it now, Thanks for your time.